# Code to read from a file and then putting it into a constructor won't work

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I'm a college student and I have a project in java and I'm trying to read from files and putting them into a constructor. The file i'm trying to read from is in this form:

```
2 Sciense [mr ali hassan  14/4/1993 ] Ali  Hhassan 13234 12/3/1998 123 1234567891234 1234567891 engineer
2 Sciense [mr ali hassan  14/4/1993 ] Ali  Hhassan 13234 12/3/1998 123 1234567891234 1234567891 null
.
.
.
etc
```

I'm trying to read the tokens from the line token by token and put each of them in my constructor. Here is my code:

i know I have a lot of flows in writing my classes , that's because i only started learning java programming about 4 months ago , however what i'm trying to do is to read the first line of the file and separate each token in it i tried to inhance my code to lock like this , 
  File F= new File ("Book.txt");

```
       Scanner fileInput = new Scanner (F);
       while (fileInput.hasNextLine()){
       String Line = fileInput.nextLine();      
       Scanner readLline = new Scanner(Line);    

       while(readLline.hasNext()){
       //reads line by line
       readBook.setNumOfAuthor(readLline.nextInt());
       readBook.SetAplicationTitle(fileInput.next(Line));
       String GetRedOf = fileInput.next();    
       ba.setStatus(fileInput.next()); 
       ba.setFirstName(fileInput.next()) ;
       ba.setLastName(fileInput.next());
       Adate.setDay(fileInput.nextInt());
       String GetRedOf3 = fileInput.next();
       Adate.setMonth(fileInput.nextInt());
       String GetRedOf4 = fileInput.next();
       Adate.setYear(fileInput.nextInt() ) ;
      //  String comma = fileInput.next();
       String GetRedOf2= fileInput.next();
       bb.setName(fileInput.next()); 
       bb.setAdress(fileInput.next());
       bb.setphneNumber(fileInput.next());
       publicationDate.setDay(fileInput.nextInt())  ;
       String getred = fileInput.next();
       publicationDate.setMonth(fileInput.nextInt()); 
       String getred1 = fileInput.next();
       publicationDate.setYear(fileInput.nextInt()) ;
       readBook.SetNumOfPUblication(fileInput.nextInt()); 
       readBook.setIsbn13(fileInput.next()) ;  
       readBook.setIsbn13(fileInput.next());  
       readBook.SetCatagory(fileInput.next());            





       }
```

Can you help me solving his issue please!

this is the error i'm having
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)

```
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1463)

at TestPublications.ReadBook(TestPublications.java:260)

at TestPublications.main(TestPublications.java:232)
```

Java Result: 1
line 260 is

readBook.SetAplicationTitle(fileInput.next(Line));

Comment: Strongly recommend you 1. read a line of the file to a String and 2. break down the string rather than try to intelligently assume that .Next is going to get you the data you want.  It will also let you properly validate all your inputs

Comment: Which line is TestPublications.java:258?

Comment: This should be easy to debug. Just set a breakpoint at TestPublications.java:258. The exception means you are trying to read something as an integer which isn't an integer.

Comment: I would highly recommend to read in line by line to use a regular expression to extract your data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sciense [mr ali hassan  14/4/1993 ] Ali  Hhassan are not valid integer.
```

**1.First read  String**

```
String str = readLline.next();
```

**2.** Use Integer.parseInt() method to **validate the integer input.**

suppose

```
try{
    Integer.parseInt(ste);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Its not a valid Integer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first line:

```
2 Sciense [mr ali hassan  14/4/1993 ] Ali  Hhassan 13234 12/3/1998 123 1234567891234 1234567891 engineer
```

scanner works as follows:

```
int numofaouthers = fileInput.nextInt(); // 2
String SetAplicationTitle =fileInput.next(); // Sciense 
String GetRedOf = fileInput.next(); // [mr

String Status = fileInput.next(); // ali
```

It's already wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

The InputMismatchException indicates that what is being read from your file doesn't match the data type you are trying to store it in. The error is at line 258 of your class (turn on line numbers in your editor).  I suspect it is one of your int's, you are either trying to read in a String to an int, or you are overflowing an int (i.e. the number you are reading in is greater than MAX_INT).

On a side note you should use lower case names for your variable names. The way you have it written it is difficult to tell a variable name from a Class name.

Here is the JavaDoc for the exception:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

Comment: i know I have a lot of flows in writing my classes , that's because i only started learning java programming about 4 months ago , however what i'm trying to do is to read the first line of the file and separate each token in it i tried to inhance my code to lock like this ,

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using regular expressions and extract data from there. Maybe something like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

String regex = "([0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) \\[(.+)\\].+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher;

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.printf("1:%s 2:%s 3:%s", matcher.group(1),
                matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
    }
    break;
}
```

That example matches 3 groups:

> 1:2 2:Sciense 3:mr ali hassan  14/4/1993

Extend the regex to the whole line and you're done :-)

Comment: i have a no argument constructer , my method reads from the file and asign each token to an attribute to the constructer , do you have any other method i can use for this problem , thanks

Comment: You line `Scanner fileInput = new Scanner (F);` creates a scanner with file name `F`, doesn't it? Why can't you use a `BufferedReader` at this point?